# Today starts my new puzzle series!

Tags: steganography

> Wow. I said I might undertake to create fresh and witty Puzzling questions because brilliant men on the internet have solved my latest ones way too speedily for my foolish conceited pride - so everyone consider this a fledgling attempt I expect qualifies for favorable attention and greater votes ...

**What is this puzzle about?**

**______**
<sup>If you're one of those PSEers who gets this instantly, consider leaving it for less experienced puzzlers to solve. Thanks!</sup>

Comment: Puzzles like this are like ciphertext - the shorter ones are harder to chip away at!

Comment: Ha! I knew you would post something like this. :P

Comment: Beat me to it :P

Comment: @Rubio - roughly how long did it take you to frame this?

Comment: An hour, roughly? Spread across two sessions.  I took a break at the hyphen ;)

Comment: Wow. I knew I would... see this today!!

Comment: @Rubio - wow! The neat thing is yours flows like a regular sentence, unlike my clumsy attempt below.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> Hey! A date I maybe predicted to appear today has truly occurred perfectly...

---

This puzzle is about:

> Pi, which is appropriate because today is Pi day (a.k.a. 14th March, or 3.14 in American style).

Because:

> The number of letters in each word form the digits of:
>
>  $\pi = 3.14159\ 26535\ 89793\ 23846\ 26433\ 83279\ 50288\ 41971\ 69399\ 375 ... $
>
>  with the hyphen in "*conceited pride - so everyone*" standing for zero

Comment: Even the dot is in the right place! Nice puzzle Rubio

Comment: And the trailing ellipsis is functional as well. :)  thanks

Comment: I particularly like the hyphen :-)

Comment: @Phylyp The title is meaningful too.

Comment: The "today" is what twigged me onto this, and gave me a respite from doing letter frequency analysis!

Comment: 8 minutes to solve. that counts as "way too speedily"

Comment: @NH. - Rubio gave an underhanded softball this time :-)

Comment: @Phylyp Sure, then "consider leaving it for less experienced puzzlers to solve." :)

Comment: For a vote I would certainly go toward these top rated solutions

Comment: @NH. [No, it really doesn't](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/79305/fastest-answers-in-all-tags?tagname=%25) :-)